# Sort and eliminating duplicates

Tags: java, sorting, bufferedreader, treeset

> Input data
>   You will read from the keyboard the text of the email that needs to be converted. It can be spread over several lines.
>
> Output data: The distinct words in the text read, in alphabetical
>   order, will be displayed one at a time.
>
> Restrictions and specifications
>   The text does not contain more than 100 words, and each word can contain up to 20 characters.
>   To shorten the execution time of your program use BufferedReader
>   The class that contains the main method must be called prog

```
import java.util.*;
 public class Main {
public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Set<String> set = new TreeSet<>();
    int size = in.nextInt();
    for(int i=0 ;i < size ;i++){
        set.add(in.next());
    }
    Iterator i = set.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(i.next());
    } 
   }
 }
```

I have to say the words only once, how exactly can I do that? That's my code!
I used the `size` variable to enter a number from the keyboard and after entering the text in the forum, but I want to read the text directly while, can I do that

Comment: So, you want to read from input while you reach a condition?

Comment: I create a while while (something = something.readline ()) and add it in a treeset as I do now with for, because, when I use for, I give a number of words that I will have as a condition after adding the text .

Comment: Look at my answer and let me know if it's what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read from input, using while, you can do this:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
Set<String> set = new TreeSet<>();

while(!in.hasNext("exit")){ //you can put any word for exit
    set.add(in.next());
}

for(String e : set){
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

This is the most simple way.

**UPDATE**(BufferedReader)

```
Set<String> words = new TreeSet<>();

try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))){

    String line;
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null && !line.equals("exit")){

        words.addAll( //add elements from List<String> into Set
                Arrays.asList( //change array with words into List<String>
                    line.split("\\s+") //split line by space -> String[] (array with words)
                )
        );

    }

}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}

for(String word : words){
    System.out.println(word);
}
```

`TreeSet` will automatically remove duplicates and sort alphabetical.

Comment: And in order to end when a blank line is found, should I put the 0 character?

Comment: It's good what you wrote, it gives me correct, but in order to be complete it should be like after I put the text to close and the program and give the result, for that I should add the 0 character or do I have to do with BufferedReader readline?

Comment: With my example you skip empty strings. You want to add them in Set? Also If I type `aaa bbb` in Set I will have 2 elements `aaa` and `bbb`.

Comment: In the problem I was specified to use bufferedreader with "readline" in a while and to eliminate duplicate words and sort them lexicographically, so I want when I put the text to end the while and the words appear in oridine lexicographic, as I did in my example, only that I used for, because I do not have a very good experience in java and do not know exactly how to use some functions.

Comment: For me it's hard to understand what exactly you want. Can you please update your question with an example of input and how result should be?

Comment: @KikoLoko Now I read your comment with `blank line`. To end while when you send an empty line you need to changer `!line.equals("exit")` with `!line.isEmpty()`